# rails backbone functions in router how to prevent hacking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have some functions in router where i do relations between different model views. But i see i can call those functions from my console and hack my self. How to stop these hacks?

example:

```
class Alfa.Routers.DropsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  alfa: (bla) ->
    console.log(bla*5)
```

console:

```
router.alfa(5)
```

i get answer

```
25
```

In my real app that way im sending monster attributes(health, strength, etc..) to player, and player does a fight with that monster attributes.

```
  send_monster_to_player: (attributes) ->
    @view = new Alfa.Views.Players.IndexView(players: @players)
    @view.send_monster_to_current_player(attributes)
```

what to do to feel safe? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're exposing router as a global, e.g.

`window.router = new Alfa.Routers.DropsRouter`

Don't do this.

Instead I recommend using an AMD loader like RequireJS or Browserify.

This will help you limit your use of globals, if done right you can get away with absolutely zero globals exposed, meaning none of your code can be executed from within the console.

Comment: yes, im defining my window.router to be rendered on my app/views/index. So, to be protected, i should  use RequireJS, and even my self i wont be able with my scripts to get the hack? :) On my view i have   attack: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    attributes = this.model.attributes
    router.send_monster_to_player(attributes)

Comment: How to call my monster view's function from my player view then? :)